# How to combine groups in Poisson regression to estimate contrast?

Tags: r, statistics, emmeans

I'm not sure if this is more a programming or statistical (i.e. my lack of understanding) question.

I have a Poisson mixed model that I want to use to compare average counts across groups at different time periods.

```
mod <- glmer(Y ~ TX_GROUP * time + (1|ID), data = dat, family = poisson)
mod_em <- emmeans(mod, c("TX_GROUP","time"), type = "response")

 TX_GROUP time     rate        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 0        1    5.743158 0.4566671 Inf  4.914366  6.711723
 1        1    5.529303 0.4639790 Inf  4.690766  6.517741
 0        2    2.444541 0.2981097 Inf  1.924837  3.104564
 1        2    1.467247 0.2307103 Inf  1.078103  1.996855
 0        3    4.570218 0.4121428 Inf  3.829795  5.453790
 1        3    1.676827 0.2472920 Inf  1.255904  2.238826
```

Now, I want to estimate the marginal count for the combined time period (2 + 3) for each group. Is it not a simple case of exponentiating the sum of the logged counts from:

```
contrast(mod_em, list(`2 + 3` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)))
contrast(mod_em, list(`2 + 3` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)))
```

If I try that the value does not come close to matching the simple mean of the combined groups.

Comment: More details needed. We need a reproducible example, and also, to see what are you getting. And there's a mismatch in your words; your equation has a sum but then you say you don't get the simple mean.

Comment: These forums stimulate improvements. For example this one suggests that `contrast()` not strip off transformations when the “contrast” coefficients are all nonnegative or when a log is involved. I think I’ll make that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest that you put both of your contrasts in one list, e.g.,

```
contr = list(`2+2|0` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
             `2+3|1` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
```

You have to decide when you want to back-transform. See the [vignette on transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html) and note the discussion on "timing is everything". The two basic options are:

One option: Obtain the marginal means of the log counts, and then back-transform:

```
mod_con = update(contrast(mod_emm, contr), tran = "log")
summary(mod_con, type = "response")
```

[The `update` call is needed because `contrast` strips off transformations except in special cases, because it doesn't always know what scale to assign to arbitrary linear functions. For example, the difference of two square roots is not on a square-root scale.]

Second option: Back-transform the predictions, then sum them:

```
mod_emmr = regrid(mod_emm) 
contrast(mod_emmr, contr)
```

The distinction between these results is the same as the distinction between a geometric mean (option 1) and an arithmetic mean (option 2). I doubt that either of them will yield the same results as the raw marginal mean counts, because they are based on the predictions from your model. Personally, I think the first option is the better choice, because sums are a linear operation, and the model is linear on the log scale.

#### Addendum

There is actually a third option, which is to create a grouping variable. I will illustrate with the `pigs` dataset.

```
> pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source + factor(percent), data = pigs)
```

Here are the EMMs for `percent`:

```
> emmeans(pigs.lm, "percent")
 percent   emmean         SE df lower.CL upper.CL
       9 3.445307 0.04088810 23 3.360723 3.529890
      12 3.624861 0.03837600 23 3.545475 3.704248
      15 3.662706 0.04372996 23 3.572244 3.753168
      18 3.745156 0.05296030 23 3.635599 3.854713

Results are averaged over the levels of: source 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Now let's create a grouping factor `group`:

```
> pigs.emm = add_grouping(ref_grid(pigs.lm), "group", "percent", c("1&2","1&2","3&4","3&4"))
> str(pigs.emm)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    source = fish, soy, skim
    percent =  9, 12, 15, 18
    group = 1&2, 3&4
Nesting structure:  percent %in% group
Transformation: “log”
```

Now get the EMMs for `group` and note they are just the averages of the respective levels:

```
> emmeans(pigs.emm, "group")
 group   emmean         SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1&2   3.535084 0.02803816 23 3.477083 3.593085
 3&4   3.703931 0.03414907 23 3.633288 3.774574

Results are averaged over the levels of: source, percent 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

And here is a summary on the response scale:

```
> summary(.Last.value, type = "response")
 group response       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1&2   34.29790 0.961650 23 32.36517 36.34605
 3&4   40.60662 1.386678 23 37.83703 43.57893

Results are averaged over the levels of: source, percent 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

These are averages rather than sums, but otherwise it works, and the transformation doesn't get zapped like it does in `contrast()`

Comment: Thanks much, I was just trying to figure transformations of contrasts the other day! Your packages are fantastic, I use them all the time. :)

Comment: Thanks rvl - unfortunately the update call just gives me the exponentiated value of the summed log counts (exp(2.41) = 11.17, exp(0.9) = 2.46 vs 7.01, 3.14). Must be my end somewhere. That's fine - I'll just work with one of your other two options. Thanks.

Comment: No, that’s exactly what it should do: sums the log counts, then back-transforms if `type=“r”`. It does NOT do the same thing or give the same result as option 2. NEITHER will give the observed marginal counts from the data, at least in general.

Comment: And the third option is basically the same as the first

Answer (score 2):

To use the example data from the package, it seems to be fine, though I'd use the grouping in the formula instead.

```
> warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool*tension, data = warpbreaks)
> warp.emm <- emmeans(warp.lm, c("tension", "wool"))
> warp.emm
 tension wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L       A    44.55556 3.646761 48 37.22325 51.88786
 M       A    24.00000 3.646761 48 16.66769 31.33231
 H       A    24.55556 3.646761 48 17.22325 31.88786
 L       B    28.22222 3.646761 48 20.88992 35.55453
 M       B    28.77778 3.646761 48 21.44547 36.11008
 H       B    18.77778 3.646761 48 11.44547 26.11008

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Sum of L and M should be 44 + 24 ~ 68 for A and 28 + 28 ~ 56 for B.

```
> contrast(warp.emm, list(A.LM = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
+                         B.LM = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)))
 contrast estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 A.LM     68.55556 5.157299 48  13.293  <.0001
 B.LM     57.00000 5.157299 48  11.052  <.0001
```

Though I'd use the grouping in the formula.

```
> warp.em2 <- emmeans(warp.lm, ~tension|wool)
> contrast(warp.em2, list(LM = c(1, 1, 0)))
wool = A:
 contrast estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 LM       68.55556 5.157299 48  13.293  <.0001

wool = B:
 contrast estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 LM       57.00000 5.157299 48  11.052  <.0001
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The second method works for me, but not the first (which seems more intuitive) - it doesn't seem to give me back-transformed values:

```
(mod_em_inj <- emmeans(mod_inj, c("TX_GROUP","time"), type = "response"))

 TX_GROUP time     rate        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 0        1    5.743158 0.4566671 Inf  4.914366  6.711723
 1        1    5.529303 0.4639790 Inf  4.690766  6.517741
 0        2    2.444541 0.2981097 Inf  1.924837  3.104564
 1        2    1.467247 0.2307103 Inf  1.078103  1.996855
 0        3    4.570218 0.4121428 Inf  3.829795  5.453790
 1        3    1.676827 0.2472920 Inf  1.255904  2.238826


# Marginal means for combined period (7 - 24 months) - Method 1 
(mod_em_inj2 <- emmeans(mod_inj, c("TX_GROUP","time")))

 TX_GROUP time    emmean         SE  df  asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 0        1    1.7480092 0.07951497 Inf 1.59216273 1.9038557
 1        1    1.7100619 0.08391274 Inf 1.54559591 1.8745278
 0        2    0.8938574 0.12194916 Inf 0.65484147 1.1328734
 1        2    0.3833880 0.15724024 Inf 0.07520279 0.6915732
 0        3    1.5195610 0.09018011 Inf 1.34281119 1.6963107
 1        3    0.5169035 0.14747615 Inf 0.22785558 0.8059515


contr = list(`2+3|0` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
             `2+3|1` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
summary(contrast(mod_em_inj2, contr), type = "response")

 contrast  estimate        SE  df z.ratio p.value
 2+3|0    2.4134184 0.1541715 Inf  15.654  <.0001
 2+3|1    0.9002915 0.2198023 Inf   4.096  <.0001


# Marginal means for combined period (7 - 24 months) - Method 2
mod_emmr = regrid(mod_em_inj) 
contrast(mod_emmr, contr)

 contrast estimate        SE  df z.ratio p.value
 2+3|0    7.014759 0.5169870 Inf  13.569  <.0001
 2+3|1    3.144075 0.3448274 Inf   9.118  <.0001
```

The values of 7.01 and 3.14 are about what I should be getting. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious in your response.

Comment: I don't know. But read the annotations below the output, which you don't show. It always says wehat it did regarding transformations

Comment: Aha, of course: usually the transformation is stripped-off by `contrast`. See the corrected answer where the `update()` call is added.

Comment: I also added a third option in the Addendum to my answer.